# Как лучше всего распарсить нетипизированный JSON?

Tags: typescript, angular

подскажите пожалуйста, еслить ли какой хорший подход для парсинга нетипизированых JSON данных.

Бекенд отдает контент JSON объектом. Данные нужно принять и распарсить.

JSON один и он большой, часть данных нужна одному компоненту, часть других и эти данные нужно получить в резолвере компонента. Однако каждый раз, когда эти данные нужны, приходится описывать интерфейс для каждого компонента.
Есть ли какое-то решение, чтобы не писать однотипные функции деструктуризации и каждый раз не описывать интерфейс, который нужен по сути один раз.

[Пример текущей реализации на Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resoilver?file=src/app/templates.service.ts)

В настоящий момент объект деструктуризуется и формируется новый объект в соответствие с интерфейсом.
Проблема в том, что для каждого роутера набор данных свой и приходится индивидуально для каждого компонента писать свой метод.

Answer (score 1):

> подскажите пожалуйста, еслить ли какой хорший подход для парсинга нетипизированых JSON данных

```
let obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```